# flask + oracle - parallel queries no longer works when called by another script (bokeh)

Tags: flask, bokeh, cx-oracle

I have a flask app with oracle as the database. If I go:

```
#app.py #SCENARIO 1
from flask import Flask, render_template
import cx_Oracle

app=Flask(__name__)

connection=cx_Oracle.connect("user","pw","xxx", threaded=True)

@app.route("/1")
    cur=connection.cursor()
    cur.execute("select col1, col2 from tbl1")
    result=cur.fetchall()
    return result
@app.route("/2")
    cur=connection.cursor()
    cur.execute("select col4, col5 from tbl2")
    result=cur.fetchall()
    return result
```

and I navigate to both routes at the same time, the query runs in parallel and returns the results.

However, if I open two different routes simultaneously that also each run queries from separate bokeh server scripts, neither is ran:

Flask

```
#SCENARIO 2
@app.route("/bokeh1")
def b1():
    bokeh_script=server_document("http://host:5006/bokeh1") 
    return render_template("bokserv.html" ,bokeh_script=bokeh_script) 
@app.route("/bokeh2")
def b2():
    bokeh_script=server_document("http://host:5006/bokeh2")
    return render_template("bokserv.html" ,bokeh_script=bokeh_script)
```

Each bokeh script `(bokeh1, bokeh2)`starts by calling the database and running a query just like in the first scenario.

```
import bokeh
from app import connection
cur=connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("Select col1, col2 from tbl1")
...
...
curdoc(p)
```

Neither pages render and are stuck in perpetual loading. Why does it work in scenario 1 but not 2? If I load the bokeh pages sequentially, allowing 1 to render before start the next, it works. Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's hard to say much without being able to run and reproduce things. Is there any output in the Bokeh server logs? What about if you sprinkle `print` statements in the script, can you see more exactly how far it gets before blocking?

Answer (score 0):

sprinkling print statements around indicates that the bokeh scripts (when you open one immediately after another) don't even run. It's really weird since the first scenario is almost the same.

Interestingly, I installed nginx and gunicorn and used a very basic configuration (borrowed from this example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kDRRtPO0YPA:

```
server {
          location \ {
                       proxy_pass host:8000;
                      }
}
```

In Flask, 
`from bokeh.server import Server`, set `num_procs=2` in `Server()`. 
Then I ran flask with gunicorn `gunicorn app:app` and was able to get 2 of 3 bokeh servers render and in parallel. The last bokeh server appears to be processing twice (I could tell via print sprinkling), the page stops loading without completing the render. If I don't figure it by midday tomorrow, I think I may make a new thread. I have no background in any of this and I'm learning something new everyday, it's crazy!